# Not getting the package and current focus information when using dumpsys adb shell command

Tags: appium-android, appium-desktop

Not getting the package and current focus information when using:   1|m21:/ $ dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus', no information is getting displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those who are going through same issue can try following command:

```
--> adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mTopActivityComponent'"
```

It is working and giving the details of the information needed

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an empty result when running the command dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mTopActivityComponent', it could mean that there are no active windows or activities at the moment.

Try closing the application and reopen again. I too had the same problem and solved when I reopen the Application

Still not solved? Here are a few things you can check:

Ensure there are active windows or activities: Make sure that apps are running on the device or emulator when you execute the command. If the device is idle or no apps are open, there won't be any output.

Check the syntax of the command: Ensure that the syntax of the command is correct, including the spacing and quotation marks. The command should be dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mTopActivityComponent'.

Verify permissions: Depending on the device's configuration, you might need elevated permissions to execute the dumpsys command. Make sure that the device or emulator is properly configured and has the necessary permissions.